# Prevent ASP.net __doPostback() from jQuery submit() within UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, forms, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm trying to stop postback on form submit if my custom jQuery validation returns false.

Is there any way to prevent the __doPostback() function finishing from within the submit() function?

I'd assumed:

```
$('#aspnetForm').submit(function () { return false; });
```

would do the trick, but apparently that's not the case: does anyone have a suggestion?

The submit() function does block the postback (it won't postback if you pause at a breakpoint in firebug), but I can't seem to stop the event happening after the submit() function is complete!

Cheers, Ed

EDIT

OK, I had a quick mess about and discovered that the fact that the button I'm using to cause the postback is tied to an updatepanel as an asyncpostbacktrigger seems to be the problem: If I remove it as a trigger (i.e. cause it to product a full postback), the is no problem preventing the postback with return false;

Any ideas why the async postback would not be stoppable using return false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the client side [`PageRequestManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976.aspx) to properly handle AJAX submit events. (e.g. prevent an async postback.)

If you are not in total control of the page, there can be JavaScript on the page that just calls `__doPostBack()` without going through any page logic.
In this case - in addition to the above -, you have to store the old `window.__doPostBack()` and provide your own - as @tucaz mentioned in his comments.
(...and as you mentioned, it can get quite perplexing with chaining.)
For regular submits (non-AJAX), you can provide an event handler as others have pointed out.

[This page](http://magmainteractive.net/tutorials/post/Building-ASPNET-35-AJAX-Script-Controls.aspx) might be of help and has some code samples that use [`PageRequestManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976.aspx). In particular:

```
initialize : function()
{
    ...

    this._onSubmitHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onSubmit);
    this._onPartialUpdateEnd = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onUpdateEnd);

    if (typeof(Sys.WebForms)!== "undefined" && typeof(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager)!== "undefined")
    {
        Array.add(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onSubmitStatements, this._onSubmitHandler);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(this._onPartialUpdateEnd);
    }
    else 
        $addHandler(document.forms[0], "submit", this._onSubmitHandler);
},
```

**Edit**:
Following the above, this, for example works fine for me (.Net 3.5 SP1, `Button1` is trigger in the updatepanel, etc...):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.js" charset="utf-8"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($, undefined) {

            var submitHandler = function(e) {
                return false;
            }

            if (typeof (Sys.WebForms) !== "undefined" && typeof (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager) !== "undefined") {
                Array.add(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onSubmitStatements, submitHandler);
            } else {
                $("form").submit(submitHandler);
            }
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I've been through the UpdatePanel docs and it seems that you can cancel async postbacks with PageRequestManager.getInstance().abortPostBack(). However, it seems that this is not working correctly: my submit() handler is no longer blocking the postback.

Comment: @Ed Woodcock: By looking at the source and article found e.g. on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163380.aspx, abortPostBack() is for canceling a request that has been *already started*.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#yourPostButton').click(function(){  
    return false; 
});
```

This should do!

Comment: Yes, but then I'd need to attach that to every button on the form, which isn't very sensible. I need to be able to do it with submit() (or some equivalent) so I can use the control that utilises the code without having to configure it on a by-the-page basis.

Comment: If it's not a problem to you you can add it to every button with $('input[type=button]') or something like that or try the .preventDefault() as suggested by jQuery documentation here http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Another idea would be get a reference do the original __doPostBack function and replace it with some dummy function if you want to interrupt the postback. Something like this: var __oldPostBack = __doPostBack; __doPostBack = function() { //check if you can post, then call __oldPostBack() }

Comment: yeah, true with the selector, but in ASP.net anything can cause a postback, such as dropdownlist selectedindexchanged (one we're using a lot), so I'd have to bind various events depending on input type, which is getting a little overly complex. As for preventDefault(), return false calls this automatically anyway, as you can see if you step through a return with firebug.

Comment: chaining __doPostBack has some issues if you try and do it more than once, which means it would get very complex when multiple controls needed to add functionality to __doPostback