# How to prevent AutoPostBack when DropDownlist is selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I want to show a confirm dialog when the user selects an item in a `DropDownList`. If the user presses <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, I want to stop the postback. Here is the function I add to the `onchange` event:

```
function imitateConfirmUnload(event) {
    if (window.onbeforeunload = null)
        return true;

    return confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?\n\nYou have unsaved changes\n\nPress OK to continue or Cancel to stay on the current page.");
}
```

And this is the relevant bit of code in my startup script to add the handler to the event:

```
function addConfirmToWarnClasses() {

    $('.warn').change(function() {
        imitateConfirmUnload()
    });
}
```

The problem is that the postback occurs even if the user selects <kbd>Cancel</kbd>. If I move the handler on to the click event, it works. But it feels clunky to me.

**Edit**

Correction: it doesn't work `onclick`, because the dialog prevents selection, so when the user selects OK, no change has taken place, and no postback when you want it!

**Edit 2**

The `DropDownList` is inside an `UpdatePanel` so that may affect behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, cancelling asynchronous postbacks from an Update Panel requires a different technique:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx

[Prevent ASP.net __doPostback() from jQuery submit() within UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424327/prevent-asp-net-dopostback-from-jquery-submit-within-updatepanel)

```
//Adds an event handler to confirm unsaved changes when an asynchronous postback is initialised by an UpdatePanel
function setConfirmAsyncPostBack() {

    if (typeof (Sys.WebForms) === "undefined" || typeof (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager) === "undefined")
        return;

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(confirmAsyncPostBack);
}

//An event handler for asynchronous postbacks that confirms unsaved changes, cancelling the postback if they are not confirmed
//Adds the confirmation to elements that have a css class of "warn"
function confirmAsyncPostBack(sender, args) {
    if (window.onbeforeunload != null && args.get_postBackElement().className == "warn" && !unloadConfirmed())
        args.set_cancel(true);
}

//Displays a confirmation dialog that imitates the dialog displayed by onbeforeunload
function unloadConfirmed() {

    var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?\n\n" + unloadMessage() + "\n\nPress OK to continue or Cancel to stay on the current page.");
    if (confirmed)
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    return confirmed;
}

function unloadMessage() {

    return 'You have unsaved changes.';
}
```

This code goes with the problem described in my other question: [DropDownList not firing onbeforeunload when AutoPostBack="True"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290758/dropdownlist-not-firing-onbeforeunload-when-autopostbacktrue)

Answer (score 5):

After reading [this solution](http://forums.asp.net/t/1650980.aspx), I just removed the `AutoPostBack` on my `DropDownLists` and used this because it was so simple:

```
$("#DropDownList1").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "0") {
        //do nothing
    }
    else {
        //do postback
        setTimeout("__doPostBack('DropDownList1','')", 0);
    }
});
```

or if you have multiple `DropDownLists` you want to make `AutoPostBack`:

```
$("select").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "0") {
        //do nothing
    }
    else {
        //do postback
        setTimeout("__doPostBack('" + this.id + "','')", 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` from that function as well, like this:

```
$('.warn').change(imitateConfirmUnload);
```

Currently the `return` value isn't being used.  This would also work:

```
$('.warn').change(function() {
  return imitateConfirmUnload();
});
```

Also, I'm *pretty* sure you want an equals check here:

```
if (window.onbeforeunload == null)
    return true;
```

Currently it's nulling out the `onbeforeunload` handler if it was present.

Comment: Thank-you for that answer. It spotted two problems very quickly. And I thought that would fix it. Surprisingly it didn't. The postback still occurs. The DropDownList is inside an UpdatePanel, so I wonder if that is affecting the behaviour....?

Comment: @Colin - Yes, absolutely. UpdatePanel changes the game completely, it's captured and handled by Microsoft scripts when it attempts to post.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is kind of old, but since it popped up in google search when I needed an answer to it, I will post solution here. I think it is simplier than those posted before.

I took it from http://forums.asp.net/p/1475520/3432980.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stopPostback()
    {
        if (blahblah)
            return true; // stop postback


        return false;
    }
</script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="if (stopPostback()) return false;">
```

The key part here is the code within onchage: to cancel AutoPostBack it has to return something (doesn't matter if true or false) and to proceed with AutoPostBack it should not return anything.

Comment: You should be trying to separate markup from behaviour. See this: http://superprofundo.com/2010/12/29/quick-tutorial-separate-behavior-and-markup-with-jquery/ Javascript events as inline attributes no longer exist in my mind. Nick Craver's code is good, but it is not the accepted answer because of the UpdatePanel