# Prevent DropDownList selection when unsaved changes exist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a page where I have four dropdown controls.  Based on the selection, I show  a grid of data with a text box on each row of the grid.  I take input from user on each control and are saved to database upon clicking Save.

Problem:

I'm struggling to alert users when there is an unsaved change on the page and they try to change dropdown value, which results in showing different set of data on the grid.

I have a hidden field which captures when there is a change on the page

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSaveFlag" runat="server" Value="false" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

I have enabled textbox change function so every time there is a change, I enable this hidden field flag to `true`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRating" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("rating") %>' Width="25" 
            ValidationGroup="rating" onchange="setPendingSaveFlag()" />

function setPendingSaveFlag(ctrl) {
    $("#hfSaveFlag").val('true');
}
```

This works fine so far and the value is set to `true` upon change of value in text box.

Now, my dropdown list is like below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRFP" Width="250" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRFP_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

I added onchange event in code behind

```
ddlRFP.Attributes.Add("onchange", "verifyPendingSave(this);");
```

My javascript for this onchange

```
function verifyPendingSave(ctrl) {
    if ($("#hfSaveFlag").val() == 'true') {
        alert('You have pending changes on the page.');
        return false;
    } else {
         __doPostback(ctrl, '');
         return true;
    }
}
```

My intention is if the value of the hidden flag is true, I show an alert, suppress postback and select whatever the value previously selected. Execute postback when it is false.

I see the alert but it is not stopping postback though I return `false`.

My else part never does `postback`.  I see control id and the actual controls in this part but I guess since it is inside a gridview, it might not be able to find the even to `postback`. I am sure somehow I am missing something very trivial.

```
else {
    alert(ctrl.id);
    var control = document.getElementById(ctrl.id);
    __doPostback(control, '');
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this is caused by the `runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"` on the declaration of the dropdown list.

Comment: i'm not quietly sure but try this 'ddlRFP.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return verifyPendingSave(this);");'

Comment: @Curiousdev - There you go!! It looks like it is working.  But, the selectedvalue is not going back to what it was.  How do I make sure that the value changed is also reset on view?

Comment: @Curiousdev - never mind; it is always stopping postback irrespective of value returned

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters - I tried already that but my else part is not doing postback.

Comment: @techspider i think we don't need _Dopostback in else part just return true in else part because if we have already set autopostback to true correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Curiousdev - You are right. I was also of the same impression.  But, it doesn't postback even if I return true or false after adding "return functionname" in change event.

Comment: @techspider please find my answer below try something like that it'll solve your problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18130830/296861

Answer (score 1):

Please find below code just remove else part from javascript

```
function verifyPendingSave(ctrl) {
            if ($("#hfSaveFlag").val() == 'true') {
                alert('You have pending changes on the page.');
                return false;
            }
                return true;
        }
```

and your onchange function called on dropdown like this

Because of the return, __doPostBack will never be hit.

```
onchange="if(!verifyPendingSave()) return false;"
```

I hope this helps

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  It worked.  Though, the selected value on dropdown is not going back to what it was. Though post back is not happening when the alert came, it still sets the value to new value.  Do I need to capture old value in javascript somehow and re-assign to make it appear that it didn't change selection?

Comment: @techspider ohh yes sorry i just lost your question you have asked in comments too, yes yes you have to save previous value in some hidden fields or on the fly for reference please find [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5PKf/2458/) here is on focus method we set previous value on fly and if return false executed we set that value to the dropdown

Comment: if I write jQuery change for value reset and javascript onchange for postback, would both execute? if so, is there an order of execution?

Comment: Remove onchange jquery function, fiddle is just for example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x5PKf/2459/) is an updated one just focus jquery function need to add set previous value to hiddenfield and than if **hfSaveFlag** is true set that hidden-field value to dropdown

Comment: I have tried various options but it never worked to retain the value

Comment: It selects the previous value into hidden element when focused, but it appears that when I change value, the focus is getting re-executed and new value is placed in hiddenvalue. So, at the end it is always showing new value instead of old value