# Getting error: Type Sys.WebForms.Menu has already been registered

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

**Scenario**
I'm working on a webform project. I've created a webpage in which I put a dropdown and a gridview inside a update panel. When Dropdown event `OnSelectedIndexChanged` rised gridview datasource bind but at the same time below error was occurred in chrome console window.

[image]

Below is my Aspx code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group ah-equal-textbox-size">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Select Role</span>
                                    <asp:DropDownList
                                        ID="ddlSelectRole"
                                        runat="server"
                                        CssClass="form-control chosen-select"
                                        AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSelectRole_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        >
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select Role</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 ah-top-bottom-margin9px">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                            <asp:GridView
                            ID="gvRoleRights"
                            runat="server"
                            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            EmptyDataText="No Data Found!"
                            ShowFooter="False"
                            BorderStyle="None"
                            CellPadding="3"
                            GridLines="Horizontal"
                            SkinID="AHGridView">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Role_ID" HeaderText="Role ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Form_Name" HeaderText="Form Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Can_View" HeaderText="Can View" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Can_Edit" HeaderText="Can Edit" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Can_Prepare_By" HeaderText="Can Prepare" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Can_Change_Status_By" HeaderText="Active" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Prepared_By_ID" HeaderText="Prepared By ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Prepared_Date" HeaderText="Prepared By Date" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and Below is my master page Scriptmanager code:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="true">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                    <%--Site Scripts--%>
                </Scripts>
            </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I've searched alot but not find any reference how to solve the below error. I also attached some reference links which I've searched on internet. If you guys have any idea how to solve below error then let me know.

[link1](https://forums.asp.net/t/1318453.aspx?Error%20AJAX%20library%20already%20registered)

[link2](http://magmainteractive.net/tutorials/post/Building-ASPNET-35-AJAX-Script-Controls.aspx)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424327/prevent-asp-net-dopostback-from-jquery-submit-within-updatepanel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be you don't need one of these:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
```

Try removing them one at a time and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Or do the reverse and start with no scripts added and add them one by one until the error triggers. You might not need a lot of those because the ToolkitScriptManager will load them automatically.

Comment: I think what I did once is used a `ScriptManager`, not `ToolkitScriptManager` and loaded individual scripts like that. Definitely worth a try to avoid conflict between ToolkitScriptManager loading scripts and you loading the same scripts.

Comment: I've commented `MenuStandards.js` line and error gone. Thanks for your prompt response.